# I am trying to set alarm on specific time using alarm manager but alarm initiated instantly?

Tags: android

This is my onclick() function.this will set target alarm

```
      SA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      SA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(id);


            }
        });

    }
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id1) {
        switch (id1) {
        case id:
            // set time picker as current time

            return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                                         timePickerListener, hour, min,false);
        }
        return null;
    }

        private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute) {
            Calendar calnow=Calendar.getInstance();
            calnow.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calnow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,selectedHour);
            calnow.set(Calendar.MINUTE,selectedMinute);
            calnow.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
             Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),alarm.class); 
            PendingIntent pendingintent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),0,       intent, 0);
             AlarmManager alarmManager =     (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

              alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calnow.getTimeInMillis(),pendingintent);
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
```

```
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
         AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)arg0.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Toast.makeText(arg0,"Alarm Started.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here problem is that I get both toasts "alarm set" and"alarm started" as soon as I click button to set alarm before reaching target alarm.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint here, `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calnow.getTimeInMillis(),pendingintent);`, what is the value of `calnow.getTimeInMillis()`?

Comment: what is TP from where You get the time?

Comment: How do you set the value of TP? Have you checked that it's definitely a time in the future? The result you're seeing implies it's a time in the past or present time.

Comment: @opiatefuchs TimePicker TP=new TimePicker(); if you have any solution kindly write me cod actualy i m new  to android so please guyz help me out

Answer (score 1):

your fault is here. so do it like that

```
          Calendar calnow=Calendar.getInstance()
           
            calnow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,selectedHour);
            calnow.set(Calendar.MINUTE,selectedMinute);
            calnow.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            if (calnow.getTimeInMillis()< System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            calnow.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is, that  the value from TP seems to be the current time. It would be helpful if You show more of Your code. Let me give You an example for setting alarm time with a delay of 5 seconds. Please try out this one, it´s a dirty way, I just want to explain. This is what You did:

```
       calnow.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,TP.getCurrentHour());
            calnow.set(Calendar.MINUTE,TP.getCurrentMinute());
          alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calnow.getTimeInMillis(),pendingintent);
```

to get a delay of five seconds, change it to

```
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   calnow.getTimeInMillis()+5000,pendingintent);
```

like I said, this is only to show which value You have to set to alarmManager. It has to be the time in milliseconds, when You want to start the alarm. For this, You have to be sure to get the right values from Your TP. So, if You want us to help You, it will be a good way to show us the complete code

Comment: Thanx for your help i have just uploaded new code please check it and help me out